# Converting from biblatex to BibTeX format using biber

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, conversion, biber

I wish to use `biblatex`+`biber`, in large part because of its data format (xdata!), but often need to use `.bst`-based bibliography styles. I am aware that `biber --tool` allows conversion of `.bib`-files. Before rolling my own, is there a biber configuration file available that does the conversion from the `biblatex` format to the BibTeX format (e.g., resolving cross/x references/data, location -> address, journaltitle -> journal, date -> year+#mon#)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try the `biber` option `--tool-resolve`. This resolves crossref/xref and xdata. To reverse the standard `biblatex` mappings you mention (which are implemented in `biblatex.def` using the standard macros in the documentation), copy the standard mappings to your preamble and edit as necessary to reverse them:

```
\DeclareSourcemap[datatype=bibtex]{
  \map{
    \step[typesource=conference, typetarget=inproceedings]
    \step[typesource=electronic, typetarget=online]
    \step[typesource=www,        typetarget=online]
  }
  \map{
    \step[typesource=mastersthesis, typetarget=thesis, final]
    \step[fieldset=type,            fieldvalue=mathesis]
  }
  \map{
    \step[typesource=phdthesis, typetarget=thesis, final]
    \step[fieldset=type,        fieldvalue=phdthesis]
  }
  \map{
    \step[typesource=techreport, typetarget=report, final]
    \step[fieldset=type,         fieldvalue=techreport]
  }
  \map{
    \step[fieldsource=address,       fieldtarget=location]
    \step[fieldsource=school,        fieldtarget=institution]
    \step[fieldsource=annote,        fieldtarget=annotation]
    \step[fieldsource=archiveprefix, fieldtarget=eprinttype]
    \step[fieldsource=journal,       fieldtarget=journaltitle]
    \step[fieldsource=primaryclass,  fieldtarget=eprintclass]
    \step[fieldsource=key,           fieldtarget=sortkey]
    \step[fieldsource=pdf,           fieldtarget=file]
  }
}
```

or do the same thing via your `biber.conf` (these are the standard mappings, just reverse the source/target specifiers according to need):

```
<sourcemap>
  <maps datatype="bibtex">
    <map>
      <map_step map_type_source="conference" map_type_target="inproceedings"/>
      <map_step map_type_source="electronic" map_type_target="online"/>
      <map_step map_type_source="www" map_type_target="online"/>
    </map>
    <map>
      <map_step map_type_source="mastersthesis" map_type_target="thesis" map_final="1"/>
      <map_step map_field_set="type" map_field_value="mathesis"/>
    </map>
    <map>
      <map_step map_type_source="phdthesis" map_type_target="thesis" map_final="1"/>
      <map_step map_field_set="type" map_field_value="phdthesis"/>
    </map>
    <map>
      <map_step map_type_source="techreport" map_type_target="report" map_final="1"/>
      <map_step map_field_set="type" map_field_value="techreport"/>
    </map>
    <map>
      <map_step map_field_source="address" map_field_target="location"/>
      <map_step map_field_source="school" map_field_target="institution"/>
      <map_step map_field_source="annote" map_field_target="annotation"/>
      <map_step map_field_source="archiveprefix" map_field_target="eprinttype"/>
      <map_step map_field_source="journal" map_field_target="journaltitle"/>
      <map_step map_field_source="primaryclass" map_field_target="eprintclass"/>
      <map_step map_field_source="key" map_field_target="sortkey"/>
      <map_step map_field_source="pdf" map_field_target="file"/>
    </map>
  </maps>
```

These are equivalent and implement the default `biblatex` mappings, it just depends on where you prefer to specify the mapping.

Comment: Yes, that is part of the solution. But I was wondering whether there was a pre-made biber configuration file that specified the other conversions as well. I think I can't be the first with the wish to use the BibLaTeX format, but often needs to use the BibTeX format and wishes to avoid maintaining two databases.

Comment: I've added the appropriate things to the answer.

Comment: Find a more complete example `.conf` file [there](https://users.aalto.fi/~mkouhia/2016/biblatex-to-bibtex-conversion/) :)