# Bibliography in LNCS doesn't work as expected

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, lncs

I'm using the Lecture Note in Computer Science (LNCS) LaTeX template, and I'm in trouble with their bibliography system.

I'm referencing a Book, but it doesn't show the information of the bib, it just prints the author and title.

Here is the template according with LNCS style:

1.Author Surname, A.: Title. Publisher, City (Year Published).

The bib file:

```
@book{ref.the.book,
author = {Lastname, A.},
title = {Title},
date = {1995},
editor = {Book editor},
location = {City, Country},
}
```

And the TeX file:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{llncs}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur\cite{ref.the.book} adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod .

\bibliographystyle{splncs03}    
\bibliography{bibfilename}

\end{document}
```

I get this:

1. Lastname, A.: Title

But, i would like get:

1. Lastname, A.: Title. Publisher, City (1995).

Does anyone have any ideas why it's happening?

Comment: Where is the `splncs03` bibstyle from? It's not part of the standard distribution. And this is what is giving you the format.

Comment: Hi Alan, here i downloaded http://45jaiio.sadio.org.ar/sites/default/files/Estilo_latex2e_0.zip

Comment: Have you tried to enter something in the `publisher=` field?

Comment: BTW, you should preferably get the LLNCS zip from the Springer web page. The version there is slightly newer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem lies in your `bibtex` file field names, which are incorrect if you are using `bibtex` to process your bibliography (which you are).  As you note in the comments, you had been using the bibliography manager included in TeXStudio, which allows you to choose between `biblatex` and `bibtex`.

`biblatex` supports a much richer data model than traditional `bibtex` and so if you use those fields you are basically stuck with using `biblatex`. On the other hand `biblatex` supports all the legacy `bibtex` fields, so unless you absolutely require the power that `biblatex` provides it's more practical to keep with the `bibtex` fields since they are usable with both `biblatex/biber` and `natbib/bibtex`.  See the following questions for more details:

- [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/2693)
- [Compatibility of bibtex and biblatex bibliography files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37095/2693)

If you do need the power of `biblatex` but you also need to use the standard format as well, `biber` can be used in `tool` mode to convert from one format to another. See:

- [Converting from biblatex to BibTeX format using biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/114787/2693)

Since you are using the LLNCS class, you cannot use `biblatex` fields, but you must use standard `bibtex` fields:

The correct field name for the date is "Year".

The correct field name for the publisher location is "Address"

And book entries have "Publisher" as a required field.

And if you look at the warnings that `bibtex` shows when you compile this you can see the issues clearly:

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015)
The top-level auxiliary file: llncs-bib.aux
The style file: splncs03.bst
Database file #1: bibfilename.bib
Warning--can't use both author and editor fields in badref
Warning--missing publisher in badref
Warning--empty year in badref
(There were 3 warnings)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks.... now it works. i'm using Texstudio and its bib manager. And i don't see any warning. I found that Texstudio had 2 types of Bib: BibTeX and BibLateX. BibTeX is the correct one, and generated the fields as you suggest. By default is BibLaTeX, so i changed that and no more problems.

Comment: @Gabriel Your comment is very enlightening. I hadn't noticed that the fields you were using were valid `biblatex` fields.  I'll update my answer to reflect that.